# BeautifulSoup is too slow. Can lxml do this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've got the following BeautifulSoup code, a bit simplified.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for item in soup.findAll('div',id=compile('^result_')):
  q = item.find('a',{'class':'title'})
  if q:
    ...
  q = item.find('div',{'class':['one','two']})
  if q:
    ...
```

I profiled it, and it's quite slow. I want to try lxml instead but it seems to be a bit unintuitive, compared to BeautifulSoup at least, and I'm not sure it can handle more complex cases.

Can the above code be converted to libxml? I don't want code, just confirmation will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [lxml supports XPath](https://lxml.de/dev/xpathxslt.html#xpath), I would argue: yes, this is definitely possible.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I was able to convert all BeautifulSoup code to lxml. It works, and is much faster. I can only recommend it.